# encoded image in base64 back to image

Tags: java, android, image, base64

so I am trying to take a string for an image I encoded using base64 and turn it back into an image I can use in an ImageView. The code to encode it is:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
image_str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I'm assuming it would be convert image_str back to a byteArray then back to bitmap?

I am not very familiar with base64 functions so I figured I would ask here while I search, to get more done in the same amount of time.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

EDIT: I did find this bit of code but the image does not show up and logcat says decode returned false:

```
byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(imageString,Base64.NO_WRAP);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Comment: You'd BASE64 decode the string to bytes, then convert the bytes back to a bitmap.

Comment: I found this:

byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(imageString,Base64.NO_WRAP);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

But it doesn't work, it says in logcat decode returned false and then doesn't show the image, but I do see that the string is there and correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd first decode the Base64 encoded string to bytes:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(image_str, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then convert the bytes back to a JPG:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
```

Comment: That did not seem to work. Logcat says decode returned false and the image didn't show up.

Comment: Then you're somehow mangling the string between encoding / decoding. That's how it works.

Comment: hmmm okay, I don't think anything is being added to the string but I'll make sure. Is there any online converter that I can check it on? Like where I can copy/paste in the encode string and it would give the image back?

Comment: And thank you for your help! And I found the converter and it worked. So there but be something being added when I send it from the server to the app.

Comment: @TylerM How is *decode* returning `false`? It doesn't return a boolean. Are you sure that's not `bitmap.compress` that's returning false?

Comment: 01-22 19:16:18.798: D/skia(17402): --- decoder->decode returned false

is what is coming up in logcat

Comment: Ah, ok - googled, apparently that's an internal thing in the `BitmapFactory`. Have you made sure that's not happening on the first call when you read the file?

Comment: In fact - try removing the Base64 encode/decode to make sure it's actually the problem.

Comment: It definitely seems like something is getting messed up when I send the string to the server and back from the server. I'll look into it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: And when I copy the encoded string from the database in the server, I only get half the image when I put it into a converter, do you think maybe the mysql table is limiting it? Is there a way to compress the image first then turn it into a string?

Comment: How did you define the column in the DB table? And the image is compressed :) It's a jpg.

Comment: I got it to work. I changed bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
To
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);